# Option Arbitrage Opportunity

Tags: options, option-pricing, arbitrage

Could you please explain me whether there is an arbitrage opportunity in this situation (added below)?

[image]

Comment: I advise you play around with various options of shorting and buying the asset and the option and see what happens in the two scenario's.

Answer (score 1):

On an expiration basis, your put protected long underlying  makes money above $80 and you have a locked in loss of \$5 below \$75.

Note that long underlying plus long put is synthetically equal to a long call.  Pretending no carry cost or dividend, your position is the same as buying the \$75 call for \$5 and the P&L is the same as stated above.

There's no arbitrage.